# Triggering function after each row in a report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm doing a report in Access. Basically (although the reality is a little more complicated, but it doesn't matter), I want to give a new row color to each new row of data (not just alternating colors, which are built in) that is generated on the report. I was hoping there was some kind of event that I could handle that fires when a new row of data is queried and then I could update `BackColor` for that control, but I haven't found any event like that. Alternatively, I was thinking I could loop through all of the rows of a given control after the report is loaded entirely, but I'm a bit iffy on how the multiple rows of information are organized in a given control (if that makes any sense). What's the best way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you investigated the `On Format` event of the `Detail` section?

Comment: That doesn't seem to fire at all, although it sounds like just what I'm looking for...

Comment: I tested and it doesn't fire if you just switch to "Report View", but it does file if you go into "Print Preview".

Comment: Huh. Yeah, it works fine there. I wonder if there's any equivalent for Report View. Surely there must be something comparable.

Answer (score 3):

> I was hoping there was some kind of event that I could handle that fires when a new row of data is queried

The `On Format` event of the `Detail` section has traditionally been the place to handle actions like you describe, but it seems to only fire when the report is "Print Previewed" or actually printed. The `On Paint` event does something similar and its effects can be seen when the report is in "Report View".